# Open CV assertion failed but its not wrong filename

Tags: python, opencv

Okay so I've been working on this project where we get a video of the traffic from the sidewalk and detect cars and read their number plates. The detection part worked well, and I got satisfactory results. Now I'm trying to extract the bounding boxes for the cars, and save them as a jpg, and I also want only the bounding boxes from a certain area in the frame. so I wrote this code, but I receive an assertion error everytime around frame 50. I dont think there's anything wrong with the video because the detection part works well. I receive the error at line 54
`cv2.imwrite("frames\\"+str(number)+'.jpg', frametosave)`
I tried both `frames\\` and `frames/` but i got an error for both pathnames. Please help me out before I get fired.

```
 import cv2
import numpy as np

video = cv2.VideoCapture("Resources/highway.mp4")
wh = 320
classpathname = 'Resources/coco.names'
classNames = []

videoWidth,videoHeight = int(video.get(3)), int(video.get(4))
size = (videoWidth, videoHeight)
result = cv2.VideoWriter('result.mp4', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG'),10, size)


with open(classpathname,'rt') as f:
    classNames = f.read().rstrip('\n').split('\n')

configFile = "Resources/yolov3.cfg"
weights = "Resources/yolov3.weights"

net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(configFile, weights)
net.setPreferableBackend(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_OPENCV)
net.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CPU)

def findObjects(output, img):
    h, w, c = img.shape
    boundingbox = []
    classIDs = []
    confidences = []

    for out in output:
        for det in out:
            scores = det[5:]


            classID = np.argmax(scores)

            confidence = scores[classID]
            if confidence> 0.6:

                width,height= int(det[2]*w), int(det[3]*h)
                x,y = int((det[0]*w )-width/2), int((det[1]*h) -height/2)
                boundingbox.append([x,y, width, height])
                classIDs.append(classID)
                confidences.append(confidence)


    indices = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boundingbox, confidences, 0.6, 0.3)
    number = 1
    for i in indices:
        box = boundingbox[i]
        x,y,w,h = box[0],box[1],box[2],box[3]
        if(y+h>1000 and x+(w/2) <1000 ):
            frametosave = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            cv2.imwrite("frames/"+str(number)+'.jpg', frametosave)
            number+=1
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y), (x+w, y+h), (255,0,255),2)
        cv2.putText(img, f'{classNames[classIDs[i]].upper()} {int(confidences[i]*100)}%', (x,y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6, (255,0,255), 2)

framenumber = 1
while True:
    success, img = video.read()
    if success:
        blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 1 / 255, (wh, wh), [0, 0, 0], 1, crop=False)
        net.setInput(blob)
        print(framenumber)

        framenumber +=1
        layerNames = net.getLayerNames()

        outputLayerNames = [layerNames[i - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
        outputs = net.forward(outputLayerNames)
        findObjects(outputs, img)
        if success:
            result.write(img)
        cv2.imshow("img", img)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('s'):
            break

video.release()
result.release()
```

This is the error I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chhet\PycharmProjects\opencv\objectDetection.py", line 72, in <module>
    findObjects(outputs, img)
  File "C:\Users\chhet\PycharmProjects\opencv\objectDetection.py", line 54, in findObjects
    cv2.imwrite("frames\\"+str(number)+'.jpg', frametosave)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.4-dev) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp:799: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'cv::imwrite'

OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x47504a4d/'MJPG' is not supported with codec id 7 and format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'
OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to use tag 0x7634706d/'mp4v'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What was the exact error message? Please post it as text.

Comment: @fmw42 I have updated the question with the errors. Please help :)

Comment: It could not find the file. Perhaps a bad frame in the video. Please do not post images of code.

Comment: it can be better to put a checker just before writing the image: `if(frametosave .data)`

Comment: save the video as `.avi` , not as `.mp4` (wrong combination of video codec / container)

Comment: this is a classic situation. so many people have encountered this error and most that ask here don't bother to investigate the arguments they pass to `imwrite`... `frametosave` must be empty. perhaps the box you used for the slice is outside of the image area. you *can* debug this... with a debugger. look at variables.

Comment: thank you @ChristophRackwitz what you said was true, i put a few conditions before writing frame to save like if x<0, x=0 and x+w> videoWidth, x+w = videoWidth, etc and it worked

Answer (score 0):

So what I did was add a few conditions to check if the frame was valid and it worked. these are the conditions i checked:

```
  if(x<0):
                x=0
            if(y<0):
                y=0

            frametosave = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            if (x + w > videoWidth):
                if (y + h > videoHeight):
                    frametosave = img[y:videoHeight, x:videoWidth]
                frametosave = img[y:y + h, x:videoWidth]
            if(y+h> videoHeight):
                frametosave = img[y:videoHeight, x:x+w]
            if frametosave.data:
                print(frametosave.data)
                cv2.imwrite("frames/" + str(number) + '.jpg', frametosave)
```